Click event handler is never executed
I'm using iwideo script to add a background video to a div element. This works fine. Now I would like to implement a possibility to pause the video by clicking on the overlay element created by the script (which has class iwideo-overlay). While I can see the script executing in an expected way (using the browser debugger) and I can see that event listener has been added to the element, the event handler is not executed when the user clicks on the element.
A demonstration can be found at codepen (I can post it here, but it might not make sense without seeing the generated markup).

In the end the culprit is the z-index: -1; style set for the iwideo-wrapper element. When I removed it, it works fine.
